# List of exceptions like .className and style.cssFloat?

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's my understanding that when setting styles using JavaScript, it's generally element.style.cssproperty = "css value";

However, when you have CSS properties like font-size and background-color, they become camelCase so fontSize and backgroundColor as Javascript doesn't work well with the hypen.

I just read this short website though, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:CSS/float, where it was explain that style.cssFloat is used as float is a reserved keyword.  I believe that is the case also with className because class is reserved.

So my main question is this:  is there a list of other such exceptions like cssFloat and className?

Secondary question:  I was using .style.float until I read the above article.  Brackets auto-suggested it and it worked fine in Chrome.  So I'm assuming that isn't true across all browsers?  Why does it work at all though?

Comment: You could just do something like run `console.dir(document.body.style)` in your browser and see all the options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ReservedWord problem**

First, the difference between an *Identifier* and an *IdentifierName* is

> [**7.6 Identifier Names and Identifiers**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6)
>
> [...] An *Identifier* is an *IdentifierName* that is not a *ReservedWord*
>   (see [7.6.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1)). [...]

And in property accessors you can use *IdentifierName*s, including *ReservedWord*s like `float` or `class`:

> [**11.2.1 Property Accessors**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1)
>
> Properties are accessed by name, using either the dot notation:
>
> ```
> MemberExpression . IdentifierName
> CallExpression . IdentifierName
> ```

The problem is that previous specifications only allowed *Identifier*s in property accessors, so `.class` and `.float` were not valid.

Therefore, web standards introduced workarounds.

**CSS IDL attributes**

If you don't want to care about CSS properties, the "most standard" way is using [`setProperty`](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-setproperty) to set values and [`getPropertyValue`](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-getpropertyvalue) to get them:

```
element.style.setProperty('float', 'left');
element.style.getPropertyValue('background-color');
```

However, for convenience, supported CSS properties (including `float`) are also available as [camel cased IDL attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-_camel_cased_attribute).

Since `float` would throw an error, the specific [`cssFloat`](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-cssfloat) was introduced.

You can see in the [*CSSStyleDeclaration*](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#cssstyledeclaration) definition that there aren't other cases like `cssFloat`.

**Reflecting IDL attributes**

Lots of content attributes are [reflected](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#reflecting-content-attributes-in-idl-attributes) by IDL attributes, and usually they have the same name. However, that's not required. For example,

- `className` IDL attribute reflect `class` content attribute because `class` was not a valid property accessor before ES5.
- `defaultValue` IDL attribute reflect `value` content attribute of an `input` element because the `value` IDL attribute represents the current value, not the initial one set in the HTML source.

Unlike CSS camel cased IDL attributes, reflecting IDL attributes are not defined "automatically". Each one is defined separately, so in fact I don't consider them exceptions. Then there is no list of exceptions.